# Website loses initial scale in Android browser

Tags: android, mobile, responsive-design, web

I've put this line in the head part of my document:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200,initial-scale=1.4">
```

It does what it is supposed to do, in both of the Mobile Chrome browser and the Android browser.

But there is a strange behaviour in the Android browser. If I have more than one browser window open, then close the browser and remove it from the list of currently running apps, wait a little bit and open the browser again and return to the window my website is in, it reloads automatically - which is no problem, but after finishing the reload it loses its initial scale and everything turns tiny on the screen.

The Chrome browser does not seem to have this problem.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this line is the solution:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200,initial-scale=1.4,minimum-scale=1.4">
```